# mips64: find instruction that causes NMI watchdog reset (error epc register)

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, mips, virtual-memory

I have a device running on mips64 that every now and again reboots due to an NMI watchdog reset. I have the contents of the err epc register which holds the contents of the instruction register when the device is reset by the NMI watchdog. The err epc register always holds a very similar address but not always exactly the same, which leads me to the assumption that the device is stuck in a loop - probably while executing an NMI.

Is there a way to figure out which instruction, preferably even which method in which module the device is executing by only having the err epc value? A first step would be to dump the contents virtual memory around the address, but I already fail in doing that.

I already checked /proc/modules and figured that all modules are loaded in different regions of the virtual memory (the failing epc is in the range of 0xffffffff80460980 - 0xffffffff804609d4, all the modules are above 0xffffffffc0000000), so I assume this is something deep in the linux kernel.

any ideas / hints on how to proceed are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In MIPS64 addresses in the range `0xffffffff8xxxxxxx` map to `kseg0` and addresses in the range `0xffffffffcxxxxxxx` map to `kseg2`.

It looks like there is no MMU on this machine and that the NMI is being triggered in an application running in kseg0 and not the kernel. If you can tell what application is running, you should be able to disassemble code around the failing EPC.